# Expression Encoder 4 / IIS 7 on Windows 7 - 400 Bad Request, no image in the

Tags: silverlight, iis-7

Hi I'm using Expression Encoder 4 with IIS 7 on Windows 7. I have tried the getting started guide and I'm running into a couple of problems. Here's what I did:

1. 1) Installed Media Services and I
   had confirmed that it had installed
   by making sure that Live Smooth
   Streaming Publishing icon is
   available under the Media Services
   section in IIS 7.
2. Next I installed
   Expression Encoder 4
3. Connected my
   webcam (Microsoft HD Cam
4. Added a
   source, selected the video input as
   Microsoft HD Cam  in Expression
   Encoder
5. Selected IIS H.264 preset
   for IIS Smooth Streaming
6. In IIS
   Live Smooth Streaming... I added a
   publishing point and saved it as
   MyWork and it saved a ISML file as
   MyWork.isml in my site root
   directory.
7. Back in Expression Encoder 4, I set the output as publishing point of : http://192.168.0.2/MyWork.isml
8. Then I opened my browser and tried 192.168.0.2/MyWork.isml

and this did not work. I received 400 Bad Request. I tried 192.168.0.2/MyWork.isml/manifest and this displayed the XML. What am I doing wrong here ?? I googled this and the only post that I've seen is an issue where the user didn't press the CUE (FYI, I had pressed the CUE and started the streaming sucessfully according to Expression Encoder 4).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add /manifest to the end of the url: http://192.168.0.2/MyWork.isml/manifest

That returns the manifest xml for the smooth streaming video. That's all you need to play that video in Silverlight using the SmoothstreamingMediaElement or the Silverlight Media Framework. Just assign that url to the player and you'll start seeing your video.